# How to fix external hard disk NTFS READ ONLY?

Tags: macos, permission, ntfs

On reinstalling MacOS Mojave, my NTFS hard drive became read-only. Previously, before reinstalling the OS I used to use applications like NTFS for MAC to be able to Read and Write on the disk, however this no longer works even though it shows I'm the admin and I have "read and write permissions"
I can copy stuff to another hard drive or to the mac, but I am not able to write anything on the disk or make changes to the existing hard drive.
I want to be able to access the hard drive without formatting as I have two years worth of documentary footage which I cannot lose or copy because I do not have a backup hard drive with the same amount of storage space.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if you’re an admin or not, NTFS is not natively supported in macOS.  You need a 3rd party solution to write to NTFS volumes

Comment: @Allan I was using a third party app and I tried multiple apps but none seem to be working, so was wondering if there is a solution by some code in the termnal

Comment: If it’s not built in to the OS, there’s no command you enter to magically make it availble.